# UTF-8 string validation for usernames, and emails?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, forms, utf-8

I am building a registration form and would like users to register with UTF-8 characters for other languages. Currently I am validating the username and email fields with this regex:

`!/^[0-9A-Za-z_]+$/` 
 However, this will not work with UTF-8 characters.

What can I do to validate 'Bob', '我是貓', etc...?

**A sub question:** Do UTF-8 email addresses even exist? For example : `我是貓@yahoo.cn`

Comment: Why do you need to validate them at all? What are you preventing?

Comment: Illegal characters? Too short/too long? An invalid email address? The usual validation...

Comment: What characters are illegal? Check the length.  Use a real email address parser, not a regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if a string is UTF-8 you can use

[mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) or perhaps some [iconv](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-get-encoding.php) trickery

From experience I know that encoding is a deathtrap. STAY AWAY :D

Validating email addresses is also quite annoying. Unless you absolutely need to I recommend you just do a simple check: is there and @ and a . .

The only way to truly verify if an email exists is to send a confirmation link or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

To use Unicode in e-mail subject lines and e-mail addresses see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047

I agree with @Fritz, just check for an '@' in an email address.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such entity as "UTF-8 character" so your question is not clear.

Non-ascii URLs are here already. URL-escaped utf-8 : http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt